# Magento 2.2.5 Override sales order item block not working

Tags: sales-order, override-block

We are working on Magento 2.2.5, override the `\Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Items` `class method _prepareLayout` but it is not working showing error.

**File : etc\module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Kh_Test" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**File : etc\di.xml**

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Items" type="Kh\Test\Block\Order\Items" />
```

**File : Kh\Test\Block\Order;**

```
<?php

namespace Kh\Test\Block\Order;

class Items extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Items
{                   

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->itemsPerPage = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('sales/orders/items_per_page');

        $this->itemCollection = $this->itemCollectionFactory->create();
        $this->itemCollection->setOrderFilter($this->getOrder());
        $this->itemCollection->filterByParent(null);

        /** @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager $pagerBlock */
        $pagerBlock = $this->getChildBlock('sales_order_item_pager');
        if ($pagerBlock) {
            $pagerBlock->setLimit($this->itemsPerPage);
            //here pager updates collection parameters
            $pagerBlock->setCollection($this->itemCollection);
            $pagerBlock->setAvailableLimit([$this->itemsPerPage]);
            $pagerBlock->setShowAmounts($this->isPagerDisplayed());
        }

        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
```

}

**Error:**

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined property:
>   Qfix\Gst\Block\Order\Items::$itemCollectionFactory in
>   .../app/code/Kh/Test/Block/Order/Items.php on line 12

Comment: add constructor with this parent::__construct($context, $registry, $data, $itemCollectionFactory);

Comment: public function __construct() {
       
         parent::__construct($context, $registry, $data, $itemCollectionFactory);
    }
I tried but it shows me This page isn’t working

Comment: Please do inject arguments like extending class. Add as similar to the block which you're extending and replace the parent with this one.

Comment: Thank your reply, I tried same way and compile i got error Kh\Test\Block\Order\Items
  Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Framework\Registry. Actual type: array; File: 
...../app/code/Kh/Test/Block/Order/Items.php